# Codeigniter Active Record Selecting Multiple Rows using Multiple Primary Keys

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm having a problem returning multiple rows dynamically.

I have an active record query that needs to return multiple rows from the same table.

```
//this will be a dynamic array of ids 
$array = array('01','02','03');

//i need to have other where conditionals as well
$cond['userlevel'] = 5;

//then add the array of ids to the conditionals array        
$cond['id'] = implode(',',$array);       

//then build the active record query
$q = $this->db->select($col->where($cond);
```

It only ever seems to return the first item in the array of ids.

Comment: Try using `$q=$this->db->select('*')->from('table_name')->where($cond)->where_in('id',$array)->get();`, maybe this will work (remember to change `table_name` to yours);

Comment: Forgot to say, this line: `$cond['id'] = implode(',',$array);` needs to be removed first.

Comment: You bet thanks. You should answer the question and I'll checkmark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE userlevel IN(?,?,?,?)", array(0,1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it will help you.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where_in('column_name',array(0,1,2,3));
```

***Note:- Make sure where_in array value should not empty otherwise it will get MySQL Error.***